# Sublime Text 2 Error saving css [ERROR 2]

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2, sublimetext

so for no reason at all, today when I tried to save my css I recieved the following error:

`[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'node', u'C:\\Users\\Weber\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 2\\Packages/JSLint/linter.js', u'--predef', u"['angular', 'document', '$', '_', 'JQuery', 'FB']", u'--sloppy', u'--indent', u'2', u'--node', u'--nomen', u'--vars', u'--plusplus', u'--stupid', u'--todo', u'C:\\Users\\Weber\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 2\\Projects\\Blog\\stylesheet.css']]
[dir:  C:\Users\Weber\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Projects\Blog]
[path: C:\Python27\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Panda Security\WaAgent\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin]
[Finished]`

And so yesterday it worked, but after doing some python and c++ stuff, I came back to HTML/CSS and I get this error with CSS, not HTML. HTML saves fine.

Edit: when I save it saves the file but the console pops up saying this error, which gets greatly annoying.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is totaly off topic.

Answer (score 0):

The JSLint plugin is upset about some configuration. You can either delete the plug-in and reinstall it, or update the settings:

Type ctrl + P to open packages menu and select 'list packages', then pick JSlint. Look for the config file and edit it.